# Maximum number of threads in a .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What is the maximum number of threads you can create in a C# application?  And what happens when you reach this limit?  Is an exception of some kind thrown?

Comment: The answer will differ if you are running on the x64 VM or the x86 VM

Comment: In my situation it's x86, but can you provide the answer for both in case someone else needs it?

Comment: I am missing an answer what happens when limit is reached. Will app crash or threads remains in waiting queue?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There is no inherent limit. The maximum number of threads is determined by the amount of physical resources available. See this [article by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773) for specifics.

If you need to ask what the maximum number of threads is, you are probably doing something wrong.

[**Update**: Just out of interest: .NET Thread Pool default numbers of threads:

- 1023 in Framework 4.0 (32-bit environment)
- 32767 in Framework 4.0 (64-bit environment)
- 250 per core in Framework 3.5
- 25 per core in Framework 2.0

(These numbers may vary depending upon the hardware and OS)]

Comment: How did you figure this out?  Do you know what .NET 4.5 is, or what 5.0 will be?

Comment: You can use this code to get the counts:   int workerThreads;
   int completionPortThreads;
   ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);

Comment: @MitchWheat a summary of the link would be great, in the case when the page is no longer available.

Comment: @pqsk: and what do you think the bulleted list is?

Comment: @MitchWheat I was wondering myself, because the linked article doesn't discuss .NET, but plain 'ol C.

Comment: This is backed up by Joe Albahari. http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Optimizing_the_Thread_Pool

Comment: @MitchWheat This goes over worker threads, how is the determination made for IO(PortCompletion) Threads

Comment: @johnny: this question is 9 years old: I'd suggest you ask a new specific question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when your application hits the maximum number of thread possible?? Does it become unresponsive and just closes by itself?? If it's a c# windows form app, does the form shown becomes grayed out and closes after??

Comment: @LoukMo: if you can't create a thread, then you have probably run out of memory! I haven't tried it, but I'm assuming a memory exception will be thrown....?

Comment: @MitchWheat in Framework 4.0 and above on 64-bit environment is 32767, not 32768. You can check it easly using this code: `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var maxWorkerThreads, out var maxCompletionPortThreads);` where value of `maxWorkerThreads` is the is the value which we are looking for.

Comment: @B.Kosmowski: ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads() "Retrieves the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active concurrently"

Comment: @MitchWheat But why did you write 32768 instead of 32767?

Comment: @Liam The link should now be fixed.

Comment: I down voted just because of the comment "If you need to ask what the maximum number of threads is, you are probably doing something wrong. ".

Comment: @matan justme : then you have gaps in your knowledge. That statement is correct.

Comment: There is also a SetMaxThreads(...) method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Markus : SetMaxThreads(...) might not do what you might expect it to .....

Answer (score 30):

Mitch is right. It depends on resources (memory).

Although Raymond's article is dedicated to Windows threads, not to C# threads, the logic applies the same (C# threads are mapped to Windows threads).

However, as we are in C#, if we want to be completely precise, we need to distinguish between "started" and "non started" threads. Only started threads actually reserve stack space (as we could expect). Non started threads only allocate the information required by a thread object (you can use reflector if interested in the actual members).

You can actually test it for yourself, compare:

```
    static void DummyCall()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000000000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var threadList = new List<Thread>();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DummyCall), 1024);
                newThread.Start();
                threadList.Add(newThread);
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

with:

```
   static void DummyCall()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000000000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var threadList = new List<Thread>();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DummyCall), 1024);
                threadList.Add(newThread);
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Put a breakpoint in the exception (out of memory, of course) in VS to see the value of counter. There is a very significant difference, of course.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend running ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads method in debug

```
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out int workerThreadsCount, out int ioThreadsCount);
```

Docs and examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 12):

i did a test on a 64bit system with c# console, the exception is type of out of memory, using 2949 threads.

I realize we should be using threading pool, which I do, but this answer is in response to the main question ;)

Answer (score 7):

You should be using the thread pool (or async delgates, which in turn use the thread pool) so that the system can decide how many threads should run.

Comment: The answer *is* to let the system decide.

Comment: @Ian: I downvoted you because the same answere was given nine months before.

Comment: Link. i don't see any mention of thread pool as anyone's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Jeff Richter in CLR via C#:

"With version 2.0 of the CLR, the maximum number
of worker threads default to 25 per CPU in the machine
 and the maximum number of I/O
threads defaults to 1000. A limit of 1000 is effectively no  limit at all."

Note this is based on .NET 2.0.  This may have changed in .NET 3.5.

[Edit] As @Mitch pointed out, this is specific to the CLR ThreadPool.  If you're creating threads directly see the @Mitch and others comments.

Comment: You are confusing CLR 2.0 and .NET 2.0 in your comment about .NET 3.5.

Comment: As far as I know the SP1 for .NET 2.0 (part of .NET 3.5) changed the worker threads default to 250 per CPU/core for thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

You can **test** it by using this snipped code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int threadCount = 0;
   try
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i ++)
      {
         new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)).Start();
         threadCount ++;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      Console.WriteLine(threadCount);
      Console.ReadKey(true);
   }
}
```

Beware of 32-bit and 64-bit mode of application.