# Asynchronus Webservices Thread limit C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

We are developing an application where in UI calls a Service(WCF) layer and a component that resides inside service layer calls external webservices asynchronously. For instance: UI sends says calls WCF layer by uploading a file, and if file has 1000 entries, currently we call external services asynchronously in a loop (BeginxxxMethod) 1000 times for response. Is this the right way of doing so? Second question: what is the maximum number of asynchronous connections that can be made? Our technology is ASP.NEt and C# 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- If you control the web service API add another method that lets you pass all 1000 args and returns all results.  This is chunky vs chatty so you only go through the cross process pain once.
- If you do not control the web service API, come up with a wrapper that makes n number of remote calls synchonously, then call this wrapper asynchonously n times.  Play around until you find the best balance between number of async calls and number of sequential remote calls per async call.

Comment: We controlled the implementation by implementing TPL and PLINQ controlling MAx threads by 10...

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right way of doing so?

Async calls are often the best way to get large batch jobs done.  I think you're looking good with this approach.  As a developer, it's often our job to see where cutting new threads no longer optimizes response times. Myles mentioned using a wrapper around a service.  I have often done this when calling 1000's of calls at a time... calling a few thousand async calls actually hurt performance (in my application), so I created functionality to group calls a few hundred (asynchronously) at a time until all x-thousand calls were finished.  This gave me the best of both worlds... I was able to find the point number of async calls at once gave me the best performance and went from there.

As far as max threads, it depends on resources, but here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app) that explains the defaults... I'll post below for ease

```
 1023 in Framework 4.0 (32-bit environment)
 32768 in Framework 4.0 (64-bit environment)
 250 per core in Framework 3.5
 25 per core in Framework 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

WE have resolved this by implementing Task Parallel library. 
Below is the pseudo code.

1. Read the file contents in to generic list.
2. Use Parallel for to process each request and set MaxDOP (Degree of parallelism) according to processor count in the server to process the request.

Thanks