# Is it bad practice to recursively call a thread method (System.Threading)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

Forgive my terminology, I'm not all that familiar with `System.Threading`, but if I have something like the below:

```
private static int _index;
private static List<int> _movieIds = new List<int>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // the below call populates the _movieIds list variable with around 130,000 ints
    GetListOfMovieIdsFromDatabase(); 

    _index = 0;
    Thread myThread = new Thread(DoWork);
    myThread.Start();
}

public static void DoWork()
{
     // do something with the value of _index (iterate through the _movieIds list) then recursively call DoWork() again

     Thread.Sleep(400);

     _index++;

     DoWork();
}
```

Is this bad practice?  I am iterating through a private static list of `int's` defined at the class level as a member, so the first iteration of `DoWork()` would use the first value of `_index` (in a way I didn't explain for the sake of simplicity), then the second iteration (the recursive call) would work with the second value `_index`, and so on.

**The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm getting a stack overflow exception after around 12 hours of running this app, and I believe it's because of the recursive calls.**

Comment: Have you looked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app

Comment: If you have not a stop condition, the program will always crash because it's recursive. Does `DoWork` method really not receive any parameters ? If so, I think you should not use recursivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You will always eventually have a stack overflow because the calling stack never has a chance to unroll.

Instead of incrementing your `index` variable via recursive calls, use a loop in your thread.

```
public static void DoWork()
{
     while(true)
     {    
          // do something with the value of _index (iterate through the _movieIds list) then recursively call DoWork() again

         Thread.Sleep(400);

         _index++;

         // break when a condition is met   
      }
}
```

Comment: `while(1)` is illegal.

Comment: @KirkWoll: My original comment did say `while(true)` but Black Frog changed it in his edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because *the thread never exits*.  You need to provide an exit condition in order for the stack to unwind.

I assume you are trying to call multiple methods *in parallel*, which recursion does not do.  It will still call the method serially, with the benefit that the *results* of one run can be used in the next.  Since `DoWork` has no results, recursion in pointless here.

I see no reason for you to call this method recursively.  At worst you could call `DoWork` in a simple loop that increments `_index`.  You could *try* using `Parallel.For` to do the work in parallel to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the concept of tail recursion.

By implementing tail recursion you don't consume another stack each time you make a recursive call.

The concept itself explains why 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/08/07/understanding-tail-recursion.aspx