# System out of memory while creating threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, client-server

I need to test a client server application. I have server running on some port and need to create around 2000 clients connecting the server. For this i am trying to create 2000 threads in c# application using following code

```
 class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample client code that makes gRPC calls to the server.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++)
        {
            CalThread cThread = new CalThread(i);                                          
        } // Exception Raised Here 
    }       
}

 class CalThread
{
    public CalThread(int clientID)
    {            
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => getDataFromServer(clientID));
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void getDataFromServer(int clientID)
    {
        try
        {
            //Channel channel = new Channel("192.168.0.123:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            while (true)
            {
               //Some code to connect to server and fetch data
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here exception occur `System.OutOfmemory` in `for loop of Main method`
However i have checked Application consume only `110 MB` memory when this exception raised ?

Why c# not let me creating threads in numbers.. ? 
I have also tried `Thread Pool`  but not working ...

Comment: I able to do it with using `ThreadPool`

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation to how many threads you can create. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app), albeit old, but still gives you a glimpse.

I have also read on `C# 5.0 in a Nutshell` that it takes about 1MB per a thread, and that is why tasks are better solutions than threads in most cases. That's also why there is a thread pool; because it takes sometime to prepare and create a lot of threads.

> Second, blocking does not incur a zero cost. This is because each
>   thread ties up around 1MB of memory for as long as it lives and
>   causes an ongoing administrative overhead for the CLR and
>   operating system. For this reason, blocking can be troublesome
>   in the context of heavily I/O-bound programs that need to han-
>   dle hundreds or thousands of concurrent operations. Instead,
>   such programs need to use a callback-based approach, rescind-
>   ing their thread entirely while waiting. This is (in part) the pur-
>   pose of the asynchronous patterns that we’ll discuss later.