# CLR Max I/O (PortCompletion) Thread Determination

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've been doing some research on I/O threads buts I'm a bit confused on how the system determines the limits.

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you specify a negative number or a number larger than the maximum number of active thread pool threads (obtained using GetMaxThreads), SetMinThreads returns false and does not change either of the minimum values.

When I Call:

```
//Max IO Threads is 1000
//max Works is set to 32767
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var maxWorker, out var maxIO);
```

How does the system determine that I can only have 1000 I/O threads, and is there anyway to increase that limit?

**As the documentation states setting the number larger than the max will have no effect**

Comment: 1000 I/O threads seems like a lot. Why do you want more?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app

Comment: @Kredns I agree it is a lot,  We're doing some load testing.  We have a lot of could that should be Implemented Async, but it is not.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi thanks for the link, but that looks like it's only applicable to the worker threads, my issue is the portCompletionThreads

Comment: You can increase your completion port threads with the second argument in `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. Such as `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(numWorkerThreads, numCompletionPortThreads)`. I'm not sure how the system determined 1000, though.

Comment: MSDN is only telling you that minThread can't be bigger than maxThread (which seems logical). But you can increase maxThread by calling `SetMaxThreads`

Comment: @WillRay This will not be able to be set above the max amount of 1000

Comment: @johnny5 Are you sure? In a quick test on my local machine I was able to raise it to 2000, at least.

Comment: @WillRay apparently it’s based on the max threads set, you need to potentially set it first if your picking a larger number than the unknown default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN is just telling you that `SetMinThread` can't be used with a value bigger than the current maximum number of thread. But that number can be changed by calling `SetMaxThread`:

```
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var worker, out var io);
Console.WriteLine(io); // 1000

ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(worker, 32000);
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out worker, out io);
Console.WriteLine(io); // 32000
```

The only limit enforced is 32767. You can't set more threads than that.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that out as you posted this.