# How to split a thread into several separate threads for efficient CPU work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

In C# I have function that do something with many string lines that I want separate to threads. For example 1000 string lines for one thread. Therefore how can  separate thread to multiple threads for efficiently using CPU?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum number of threads in a .NET app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145312/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-net-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parallel.Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) allows you to split the work from an IEnumerable into multiple parallel parts and you can control the maximum number of threads that can process that enumeration.

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(
    stringLines,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 42 },
    line=> { DoWork(line); }
);
```

Comment: [System.Environment.ProcessorCount])https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount) would give you the number of processors available. There's no maximum number of threads (tehnically not true, but it's a very large number which you shouldn't bother with). Depending on the work you're doing you can decide how many threads you need; As a good practice you shouldn't need to use more threads than the number of CPU cores because they will never all run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i mean how can define concrete number for example 42? without knowing max?

Comment: I just picked a [random number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)). you know your workload better and you should be able to come up with a better number

Comment: Ok, counterquestion, Parallel.ForEach will automatically "separate function to threads" if so, will be Parallel.ForEach use CPU cores in max possible for application thread?

Comment: That's implementation detail. You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism). If you really want to control the number of threads, just created them [yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread), but if you need them there's a possibility you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I think Parallel.ForEach is that i need... now testing.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` isn't the ultimate solution. It has its own pros and cons. And I would say quite a lot of drawbacks. There are numerous ways to achieve what you need. Just pick the right now for your case

Comment: @OlegI Which best way you can advise?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is very CPU heavy. If it will be running on the client-side, it's fine. But if you are willing to put it on the server, it can simply put the machine down very quickly. Look at ` PLINQ ` it consumes less CPU